# How to extract integers from a string

Tags: php, string, height, int

I'm trying to convert a string for a height, to inches, so basically the string `$height = "5' 10\""` needs to be converted to 70 inches.

How would I go about getting the two int values out of the string?

this is a section of my database update file

```
$height = $_GET['Height'];

$heightInInches = feetToInches($height); //Function call to convert to inches
```

This is my function to convert the height to inches:

```
function feetToInches( $height) {
preg_match('/((?P<feet>\d+)\')?\s*((?P<inches>\d+)")?/', $feet, $match);
$inches = (($match[feet]*12) + ($match[inches]));

return $inches;

}
```

It just outputs 0 every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
$height = "5' 10\"";

$height = explode("'", $height);      // Create an array, split on '
$feet = $height[0];                   // Feet is everything before ', so in [0]
$inches = substr($height[1], 0, -1);  // Inches is [1]; Remove the " from the end

$total = ($feet * 12) + $inches;      // 70
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with regexp

```
<?php
$val = '5\' 10"';
preg_match('/\s*(\d+)\'\s+(\d+)"\s*/', $val, $match);
echo $match[1]*12 + $match[2];
```

the `\s*` is just in case there are leading or trailing whitespaces.

http://ideone.com/qoa6xu

---

Edit:
you're passing the wrong variable to `preg_match`, pass the `$height` variable

```
function feetToInches( $height) {
    preg_match('/((?P<feet>\d+)\')?[\s\xA0]*((?P<inches>\d+)")?/', $height, $match);
    $inches = (($match['feet']*12) + ($match['inches']));

    return $inches; 
}
```

http://ideone.com/1T28sg

Comment: I used `'/((?P<feet>\d+)\')?\s*((?P<inches>\d+)")?/'` incase the inches or feet were not present in the matches. And then the named parameters for simplicity. But other than that pretty much the same.

Comment: I cant figure out why but I cant get it to work, I think it has something to do with the way im getting the string. Its being accessed through a $_GET array, is there something else I need to change? $height = $_GET['Height']; then I call $heightInInches = feetToInches($height);

Comment: @Musa im not sure why I had my code wrong at the top but thats not what it was when I was testing it. Im passing preg_match the right variable, I echoed the $height variable and it gave me this (6\' 0\") could that be my problem? thanks for all the help so far I feel like im close

Comment: @PatrickYouells it looks like you have [magic qoutes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) on, you should turn this off. If not youll have to change the expression to `/((?P<feet>\d+)\\\\\')?\s*((?P<inches>\d+)\\\\")?/`

Comment: @Musa its pretty much working except for the inches now, inches doesnt show up in the array, affectively giving it the value of zero. I will have to look up how to get rid of magic quotes! thanks!

Comment: @Musa this is what its giving me `6\' 3\"
Notice: Undefined index: inches in /home/proj3/dynamic_php/database_edit/database_functions.php on line 22

Array
(
    [0] => 6\'
    [1] => 6\'
    [feet] => 6
    [2] => 6
)

72`

Comment: @PatrickYouells have you turned off magic quotes or are you using the other expression. see also http://ideone.com/U3Z5zi

Comment: @Musa I turned them off, and used the original expression, its still not finding anything for inches, now when I echo height it gives me '6' 3"'

Comment: @Musa by any chance, could this be messing anything up? the GET parameter in the URL is Height=6%27%A03%22

Comment: @PatrickYouells Height decoded is `6'á3"`, try `/((?P<feet>\d+)\')?á((?P<inches>\d+)")?/` and see if it works

Comment: @Musa with magic quotes disabled, `6' 3"` with them enabled `6\' 3\"`

Comment: @PatrickYouells I'm out of ideas, try one of the other answers.

Comment: @Musa thanks I appreciate the help. Im clueless as to why its not working either, I dont understand why it would accept the feet but the the inches

Comment: @PatrickYouells Height is actually decoded as `6' 3"` the space is a nbsp apparently `\s` doesn't pick it up. http://ideone.com/1T28sg

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode(" ",$height);

$feet = (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $parts[0]);

$inches = (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $parts[1]);
```